# Post Method error while uploding content to s3 bucket using cdn in aws

Tags: amazon-s3, post, aws-cdn

I am facing some issues While using cdn to upload some content to my S3 bucket.

- Using POST method to upload content not working
- While PUT and GET is Working for the same bucket policy

S3 bucket region used is us-east-1

Followed aws doc but not got solution.

demo cloudfront url

https://dqjesdd0w1dnq.cloudfront.net

and trying to post method to upload file
using aws auth in postman and adding file to upload.

Documentation urls

[URL1](https://kumargaurav1247.medium.com/aws-cdn-content-delivery-network-cloudfront-with-hands-on-e074b0e77166#:%7E:text=Amazon%20S3%20is%20designed%20for,close%20to%20users%20as%20possible.) [URL2](https://community.signalusers.org/t/using-aws-cloudfront-cdn-in-signal-application/9078/6) [URL3](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/getting-started/S3/) [URL4](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/)

```
Error
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
<Message>x-amz-content-sha256 must be UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD, STREAMING-AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD, STREAMING-AWS4-ECDSA-P256-SHA256-PAYLOAD or a valid sha256 value.</Message>
<ArgumentName>x-amz-content-sha256</ArgumentName>
<ArgumentValue>null</ArgumentValue>
<RequestId>1CHMT0X9A80DDJ1D</RequestId>
<HostId>r0xIE3tcRGPjrdmKMXvqJHPKtFPOxQ8UWpYA5OxYva+BkgZEH+m/YfsRshls+u/X4xB1ugIxZU4=</HostId>
```

*Any Help will be appreciated*

Comment: can you add details on how you are trying to upload and what documentation you are referring.

Comment: @GSSwain tried to update as you asked

Comment: Can you add your POST HTTP queries details ?

Comment: You have to sign the URL with header `x-amz-content-sha256`... but the question doesn't show the least attempt or code to produce the error - which is the reason why I've downvoted it for being completely abstract. It is not even clear which language to use.

Comment: I'm facing same issue. AWS document suck.